# How to get file name using `URLUtil`?

Tags: java, android, parsing, url

How to guess the possible file name before downloading it? I am using `String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);` but it only returns the file name, not the extension. Extension is always returned ".bin". How do I fix this? I have searched everywhere on the internet.

Comment: If the file don't have extension then URLUtil adds `.bin` to it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note**: If the file don't have extension then **`URLUtil`** adds `.bin` to it automatically

```
String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(Url, null, null);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    if (guessedFileName.contains(".gif")) {
        // GIF file
        mimeType = "image/gif";
    } else if (guessedFileName.contains(".jpg") || guessedFileName.contains(".jpeg")) {
        // JPG file
        mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    } else if (guessedFileName.contains(".png")) {
        // PNG file
        mimeType = "image/png";
    } else if (guessedFileName.contains(".txt")) {
        // Text file
        mimeType = "text/plain";
    } else if (
        guessedFileName.contains(".mpg") ||
        guessedFileName.contains(".mpeg") ||
        guessedFileName.contains(".mpe") ||
        guessedFileName.contains(".mp4") ||
        guessedFileName.contains(".avi") ||
        guessedFileName.contains(".3gp") ||
        guessedFileName.contains(".3gpp")  ||
        guessedFileName.contains(".3g2")
    ) {
        // Video files
        mimeType = "video/*";
    } else if (guessedFileName.contains(".doc") || guessedFileName.contains(".docx")) {
        // Word document
        mimeType = "application/msword";
    } else if (guessedFileName.contains(".pdf")) {
        // PDF file
        mimeType = "application/pdf";
    } else if (guessedFileName.contains(".ppt") || guessedFileName.contains(".pptx")) {
        // Powerpoint file
        mimeType = "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
    } else if (guessedFileName.contains(".xls") || guessedFileName.contains(".xlsx")) {
        // Excel file
        mimeType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    } else if (guessedFileName.contains(".rtf")) {
        // RTF file
        mimeType = "application/rtf";
    } else if (guessedFileName.contains(".apk")) {
        mimeType = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
    } else if (guessedFileName.contains(".eml")) {
        mimeType = "message/rfc822";
    }
```

A brief explanation is available: [Here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=android.webkit.URLUtil&method=guessFileName)

Comment: I liked your approach so I decided to look up something similar but with more extensions. I've found this class on github, But can't figure out how to use it from my activity https://github.com/Doist/TodoistMimeUtils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/todoist/mimeutils/MimeUtils.javav

Comment: I have tried `MimeUtils.guessExtensionFromMimeType(null)` but its crashing

Comment: sorry here is the working link https://github.com/Doist/TodoistMimeUtils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/todoist/mimeutils/MimeUtils.java

Answer (score 0):

```
String nameOfFile = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, null);
```

it works for me